# XML Children to existing Xml node

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the folowing XML

```
<Root>
..
   <someChild>3</someChild>
..
</Root>
```

The same thing in xsd will be like below

```
<xs:complexType name="RootType">
...
 <xs:element name="someChild" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>doc</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="str:secstrtype">
                <xs:maxLength value="25"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:element>
....
</xs:complexType>
```

Now the requirement has changed, this someChild can have more than one value. So, I'm thinking about the xml to be like below, so, legacy servers will get the data they used to get, but the new servers will be able to lookup the children and perform other operations. Is there a way to deal with this type of problem?

```
 <Root>
    ..
       <someChild>3
                  <someChild>
                       5
                             <someChild>
                                  9 
                             </someChild> 
                  </someChild>

       </someChild>
    ..
  </Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type of `someChild` to a `mixed` `complexType` but you will lose the ability to control the type (and restrictions such as length) of the text data:

```
<xs:element name="someChild">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="someChild" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This will validate the instance you suggested, but the text contents will be treated as plain text.